# how to set focus on NSMenu (make it get key events)?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, arrow-keys

I have a status menu with a NSSearchField and menu items. When search field is active and user presses up & down arrows, I'd like to start menu tracking, that is that the user will be able to move with arrow keys between menu items. I can catch moveUp and moveDown selectors. How can I cause the menu to become a key responder?

Thanks,

Nava

Comment: Nava Carmon: Are you talking about leaving the search field and navigating the field's parent menu, or entering the field's pop-up menu?

Comment: Leaving the search field and navigating the parent menu with up and down arrows. How do i take the focus from search field and pass it to NSMenu? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire a kCGEventMouseMoved event on mouseUp/Down. Show/hide cursor on your choice...
The main challenge here is find the right origin (global mouse point). Someone has an idea how to find a NSMenuItem rect?

```
CGEventRef mouseEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, NSPointToCGPoint(globalOrigin) , kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, mouseEvent);
CFRelease(mouseEvent);
```